# Finding the mode of a Ruby Array (simplified_

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to find the mode of an Array.  Mode = the element(s) that appear with the most frequency.

I know there are lots of tricks with #enumerable, but I'm not there yet in my learning. The exercise I'm doing assumes I can solve this problem without understanding enumerable.

I've written out my game plan, but I'm stuck on the 2nd part. I'm not sure if it's possible to compare a hash key against an array, and if found, increment the value.

```
def mode(array)    
  # Push array elements to hash.  Hash should overwrite dup keys.
  myhash = {}
  array.each do |x|
      myhash[x] = 0
  end

  # compare Hash keys to Array.  When found, push +=1 to hash's value.    

  if myhash[k] == array[x]
    myhash[k] += 1
  end

  # Sort hash by value
  # Grab the highest hash value
  # Return key(s) per the highest hash value
  # rejoice!
end

test = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
mode(test) # => 3, 6 (because they each appear 3 times)
```

Comment: Please define "mode", including the case where the array is `[1,1,2,2]`. Also, your example has an ordered array. Is it a given that the array is sorted smallest to largest? Try to be as complete and as precise as you can when asking questions.

Comment: My apologies.  By "mode" I am looking for the element(s) that appear with the most frequency.  In the example the answer would be 3 & 6 (each appearing 3 times).  You bring up a good point - I may also need to build in a .sort to handle any non-ordered arrays.

Comment: CJ, when clarifying, it's best to edit your question rather than explaining in comments, as not everyone reads the latter. Whenever you edit, you should not change what you had before. Instead, identify the edit. Some SO members write: "**Edit:** ...". It doesn't have to be at the end of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [hash with a default initial value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new):

```
myhash = Hash.new(0)
```

Then increment specific occurrences:

```
myhash["foo"] += 1
myhash["bar"] += 7
myhash["bar"] += 3
p myhash    # {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>10}
```

With that understanding, if you replace your initial hash declaration and then do the incrementing in your `array.each` iterator, you're practically done.

```
myhash.sort_by{|key,value| value}[-1]
```

gives the last entry in the sorted set of hash values, which should be your mode. Note that there may be multiple modes, so you can iterate backwards while the value portion remains constant to determine them all.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways you could do this.  Here are a few.

**#1**

```
array = [3,1,4,5,4,3]
a = array.uniq                   #=> [3, 1, 4, 5]
         .map {|e| [e, array.count(e)]}
                                 #=> [[3, 2], [1, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
         .sort_by {|_,cnt| -cnt} #=> [[3, 2], [4, 2], [1, 1], [5, 1]]
a.take_while {|_,cnt| cnt == a.first.last}
                                 #=> [[3, 2], [4, 2]]
 .map(&:first)                   #=> [3, 4]
```

**#2**

```
array.sort                       #=> [1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
     .chunk {|e| e}
       #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001021820b0>:each>
     .map { |e,a| [e, a.size] }  #=> [[1, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
     .sort_by { |_,cnt| -cnt }   #=> [[4, 2], [3, 2], [1, 1], [5, 1]]
     .chunk(&:last)
       #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000103037e70>:each>
     .first                      #=> [2, [[4, 2], [3, 2]]]
     .last                       #=> [[4, 2], [3, 2]]
     .map(&:first)               #=> [4, 3]
```

**#3**

```
h = array.each_with_object({}) { |e,h|
      (h[e] || 0) += 1 }         #=> {3=>2, 1=>1, 4=>2, 5=>1}
max_cnt = h.values.max           #=> 2
h.select { |_,cnt| cnt == max_cnt }.keys
                                 #=> [3, 4]
```

**#4**

```
a = array.group_by { |e| e }     #=> {3=>[3, 3], 1=>[1], 4=>[4, 4], 5=>[5]}
         .map {|e,ees| [e,ees.size]}
                                 #=> [[3, 2], [1, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
max = a.max_by(&:last)           #=> [3, 2]
       .last                     #=> 2
a.select {|_,cnt| cnt == max}.map(&:first)
                                 #=> [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, you have first initialized a hash containing keys taken from the unique values of the array, with the associated values all set to zero. For example, the array `[1,2,2,3]` would create the hash `{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}`.

After this, you plan to count the instances of each of the values in the array by incrementing the value for the associated key in the hash by one for each instance. So, after finding the number `1` in the array, the hash would look like so: `{1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0}`. You clearly need to do this for each value in the array, so given your approach and current level of understanding, I would suggest looping through the array again:

```
array.each do |x|
  myhash[x] += 1
end
```

As you can see, we don't need to check that `myhash[k] == array[x]` since we have already created a key:value pair for each number in the array.

However, while this approach will work, it's not very efficient: we're having to loop through the array twice. The first time to initialize all the key:value pairs to some default (zero, in this case), and the second to count the frequencies of each number.

Since the default value for each key will be zero, we can remove the need to initialize the defaults by using a different hash constructor. `myhash = {}` will return `nil` if we access a key that doesn't exist, but `myhash = Hash.new(0)` will return `0` if we access a non-existent key (note that you could provide any other value or variable, if required).

By providing a default value of zero, we can get rid of the first loop entirely. When the second loop finds a key that doesn't exist, it will use the default provided and automatically initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mode(array)
    array.group_by{ |e| e }.group_by{ |k, v| v.size }.max.pop.map{ |e| e.shift }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `simple_stats` gem:

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
test.modes #=> [3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an unsorted array, we can sort the array in descending order

```
array = array.sort!
```

Then use the sorted array to create a hash default 0 and with each element of the array as a key and number of occurrence as the value

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
array.each {|i| hash[i] +=1 }
```

Then mode will be the first element if the hash is sorted in descending order of value(number of occurrences)

```
mode = hash.sort_by{|key, value| -value}.first[0]
```